# global tmux logging with rotation and cleanup

Tags: ubuntu, logging, tmux

Is it possible to configure tmux so that whatever sessions are created, executed, closed tmux would automatically create appropriate directory with unique session name, log all the output of those sessions into the files, rotate them and delete the old ones...

This would be one global solution to logging if all your services are being run in tmux and output to stdout/err.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, and the command for saving the contents of the current pane is

```
capture-pane -S - -E - ; save-buffer ~/path/to/logfile ; delete-buffer
```

There are many variables available, so that you can do things like

```
capture-pane -S - -E -
save-buffer ~/path/to/#{session_name}/#{window_name}/#{pane_id}
delete-buffer
```

You can run shell commands with `run-shell`. You can set up hooks for various events (e.g. `session-created`, `pane-exited` (triggered when a command in a pane exits, `session-closed`) with `set-hook`.

Have a look at the manual (`man tmux`) for more details. Though, I don't know if this is the best solution for logging.